# Approximation of Natural Logarithm using arithmetic.

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, numerical-methods, logarithms

A friend of mine posed this question to me a couple days ago and it's been bugging me ever since. He told me to take the square root of 5 twenty times, subtract 1 from it, and then multiply it by 2^20, giving me a rough approximation of ln (5). I can't for the life of my figure out why this is.

Also: How can you find the natural log of any positive number X using only arithmetic operations (+, x, -, /) and square root?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. Repeatedly taking the square root of any number $x > 1$ always yields a number $x > 1$, so your friend's estimate for $\ln 5$ is $> 2^{20}$...

Comment: If you take the roots, subtract 1 from the result, and then multiply by $2^{20}$, then you do seem to get close to $\ln(5)$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include the subtraction. Post edited.

Comment: Do you have somr calculus background? The problem is rather straightforward in those terms.

Comment: I do, I've taken up to differential equations. I haven't dealt with sequences and series in some time, however.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $a$ be a positive real number.

Then 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(a^\frac1n-1)\cdot n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{a^{\frac1n}-1}{\frac1n}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{a^\frac1n\cdot\ln a\cdot\frac{-1}{n^2}}{\frac{-1}{n^2}}=\ln a$$

Your result is a special case of this with $a=5$, and $n=2^{20}$

Comment: I don't see what you did between the second and third expressions?

Comment: I applied L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Wouldn't a simpler approach to the second equality just be to recognize this as the definition of the derivative?

Comment: @Semiclassical: Yes, nice observation!  I didn't think of that.

Answer (score 2):

I checked this in Mathematica. It really does seem to converge to Log(5) accurately after many iterations:

```
a = N[Sqrt[5], 30];
Do[
 a = Sqrt[a], {n, 1, 10000 - 1}]
(a - 1)*2^10000
```

Output:

1.60943791243410037460075933323

compared to:

```
N[Log[5], 30]
```

1.60943791243410037460075933323

Comment: Apparently, this friend has either fiddled with a calculator for a long time or has figured out some extremely nice approximation technique (which hopefully someone will reverse engineer). Predicting this kind of convergence is otherwise a miraculous coincidence.

Comment: @Nick It's a consequence of the fact that $\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{a^\epsilon-1}\epsilon=\ln a$, which is easily proven with L'Hôpital. Take $\epsilon=2^{-20}$ for the approximation.

Comment: @Nick Related: We also have $\lim_{\epsilon\to0}\frac{(1+a)^\epsilon-1}\epsilon=\ln(1+a)$. Using the (Newton's) binomial theorem and simplifying, this gives us the series expansion of $\ln(1+a)$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no expression for $\ln$, which is a transcendental function, in terms of radical functions and the usual arithmetic operations, whose combinations are, by contrast, algebraic functions.

You can, however, produce arbitrarily good approximations of $\log$ (or any other continuous function for that matter) on any closed interval $[a, b] \subset (0, \infty)$.

For a relatively simple example, for $x \in (-1, 1)$ we have the *Maclaurin series*
$$\ln(1 + x) = \sum_{k = 1}^{\infty} (-1)^{k + 1} \frac{x^k}{k},$$
and we can produce variously good approximations to $\ln(1 + x)$ on that interval by simply discarding all of the terms of the series after some point. (Notice that this always produces a polynomial approximation.)

Comment: But how do you get from maclaurin approximations of the natural logarithm to something that includes the procedure described above?

Comment: I would be surprised if there were a way to use Maclaurin series to do so, but quite possibly there's some other series that could be exploited to that end.